# How to use (string Obj) sent as parameter to avoid each time use name of model

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

How to replace (string Obj) by MachineSettingModel.
How to use (string Obj) sent as parameter to avoid each time use name of model.

```
public static async Task<List<MachineSettingModel>> GetData(string Obj,string uri)
{
    List<MachineSettingModel> Object = new List<MachineSettingModel>();
    try
    {
        using (var response = await ApiHelper.ApiClient.GetAsync(uri))
        {           
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var JsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<string>();
                    Object = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MachineSettingModel[]>(JsonString).ToList();
                }                            
            return Object;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: do you want to avoid this parameter from calling function? But you want this obj in method ?

Comment: Welcome to SO! btw, its a bit difficult to understand your question. can give more context with some examples to understand what you are trying to achieve.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I understand your question is, that you want to be able to use the same method to get a list of different kinds of data. For this you should use a [generic method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-methods) instead. Something like this:

```
public static async Task<List<T>> GetData2<T>(string uri)
    where T : new() // Has to be a concrete class with a parameterless constructor
{

    List<T> resultList = new List<T>();

    try
    {
        using (var response = await ApiHelper.ApiClient.GetAsync(uri))
        {           
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var JsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<string>();
                resultList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(JsonString);
            }                            
            return resultList;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then call it like so:

```
var data = GetData2<MachineSettingModel>(someUri);
//...
var data = GetData2<SomeOtherModelType>(someOtherUri);
```